# Problems Installing puma ruby gem on OS X El Capitan 10.11

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, puma

When attempting to install puma "any version" on OS X El Capitan it kept failing. Thankfully, [/user/dennis-best](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1291663/dennis-best) was able to shed some light and deserves all the credit for this.

Comment: With OpenSSL installed via Brew and Ruby 2.2.2 installed via `rbenv` and `ruby-build`, the `puma` gem built and installed right off the bat without any issues. What's your system look like?

Comment: OpenSSL not installed via brew, rvm Ruby 2.2.3, installed puma and it was failing. You shouldn't have to install OpenSSL via brew though, it's an included package that's pre-installed with OSX. This is another viable solution though if you've installed it with brew as it's automatically linked via brew and setup to be tracked in your `$PATH`. Good note @mwp.

Comment: OpenSSL does indeed come with OS X 10.11, however, the headers (that are needed to compile against OpenSSL) do not. If you google around you'll see that it's a common issue. /usr/local/opt/openssl/include is not present in a fresh install of 10.11 so I suspect it was installed on your system some other way.

Answer (score 2):

For people who are having issues with puma and openssl, particularly with Mac OS 10.11 (El Capitan), adding some flags will save you hours and hours of heartache:

```
gem install puma -- --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
```

https://gist.github.com/edvinasbartkus/0e99ea8305a20737f562

Answer (score 0):

As [/users/mwp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1021515/mwp) mentioned you can also install OpenSSL via brew and without including the optional cppflags install puma without any hiccups. For those that don't wish to install OpenSSL via brew, the option below also works.